# Reset position pointer to replace all occurrences of a pattern until delimiter in single step using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Is it possible to use `preg_replace` to replace all occurrences of a pattern until a specified delimiter?

I want to replace multiple occurrences of a pattern, not the whole string before the delimiter.

Is it possible to do this in a single step, without splitting the string?
Is it possible to specify that the position pointer should be reset to the beginning after every replacement? Can I use lookahead to achieve this?

For example, I want to replace all occurrences of `//` in the following urls, until the `?` character.

Input:

```
https://www.example.com//abc/def/ghi/?jkl=mno//pqr
https://www.example.com//abc/def//ghi/?jkl=mno//pqr
https://www.example.com//abc//def//ghi/?jkl=mno//pqr
```

Expected Output:

```
https://www.example.com/abc/def/ghi/?jkl=mno//pqr
```

Please note

- There may be zero or more occurrences of `//` in the subject string
- Any occurrence of `//` after the delimiter `?` is left untouched.
- It can be done by splitting the string first. But I am looking for a regex only solution.

Comment: @downvoter: Why is this question broad? The question is very specific. I am looking for a regex solution to a very specific problem, with input and expected output. Please give constructive criticism and share why you think this question is broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current accepted answer is good enough to be a solution but suffers from some issues that may cause problems in near future:

- It *really* doesn't stop matching right after reaching the first occurrence of `?`
- It only works on `https` protocol (you need to add others manually to lookbehind).

Regex:

```
(^\w+:/|\G[^?/]*)/+
```

Above regex invokes `\G` which matches a position right where the previous match ends. It means when a `?` is found it can't continue matching.

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/AiSOq6/2)

PHP:

```
echo preg_replace('@(^\w+:/|\G[^?/]*)/+@', '$1/', $url);
```

Please note that you may need `(?!^)` before `\G` if there is a chance that first side of alternation couldn't satisfy e.g. in `://example.com`

Comment: Love your work. I was playing with `\G` but was missing the use of `\K` to deal with the `http/https` issue. @JoyceBabu you should accept this answer.

Comment: Thank you @revo for introducing me to `\K` and `\G`.

Comment: @Nick I'd rather say this is an add-on complementary to your answer so no need to change the acceptance mark place. `\K` is good but we can do it without it. I'll update in a few minutes.

Comment: @JoyceBabu My pleasure.

Comment: @revo I disagree entirely. Your solution actually does exactly what OPs question title asks for. As you correctly pointed out, mine does not and has limitations.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a positive lookahead to ensure that the `//` is followed by a `?`:

```
$urls = array('https://www.example.com//abc/def/ghi/?jkl=mno//pqr',
'https://www.example.com//abc/def//ghi/?jkl=mno//pqr',
'https://www.example.com//abc//def//ghi/?jkl=mno//pqr');
foreach ($urls as $url)
    echo preg_replace('#//(?=.*\?)#', '/', $url) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
https:/www.example.com/abc/def/ghi/?jkl=mno//pqr
https:/www.example.com/abc/def/ghi/?jkl=mno//pqr
https:/www.example.com/abc/def/ghi/?jkl=mno//pqr
```

**Edit**

As @revo points out, this is also removing the `//` after `https:`. To avoid that, add a negative lookbehind:

```
foreach ($urls as $url)
    echo preg_replace('#(?<!https:)//(?=.*\?)#', '$1/', $url) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
https://www.example.com/abc/def/ghi/?jkl=mno//pqr
https://www.example.com/abc/def/ghi/?jkl=mno//pqr
https://www.example.com/abc/def/ghi/?jkl=mno//pqr
```

Comment: I was under the impression that both lookahead and lookbehind required fixed with pattern. I just realized that the restriction is only for lookbehind. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you have answered the question too fast :-). SO is asking me to wait 5 minutes before accepting your answer.

Comment: Um, sorry?! :-)

Comment: Note that this doesn't stop matching until first occurrence of `?`. It basically depends on input string: `https://www.example.com//abc//def//ghi/?jkl=mno//pqr?`